# Use JQuery Datepicker on dynamically created fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to use datepicker in wordpress site, in which a plugin creates fields dynamically with same name(array), same #id and same .class i try to use it using focus but i got error on it

```
TypeError: inst is undefined
```

Please hel

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="assests/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="assests/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="assests/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="mytemplate" style="display: none;">
                <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="name[]">
            </div>
            <div class="dates">
            <div>
                <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="name[]">
            </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Add more" onclick="myfunction()">
            <script>
                function myfunction() {
                    $(".mytemplate").clone().removeClass("mytemplate").show().appendTo(".dates");
                }
            </script>
            <script>
                $(document).on("focus", "#datepicker", function(){
                    $(this).datepicker();
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can only have a single Id of datepicker (or anything, for that matter) on the page at any time. Your current selector selects them all.

Comment: You should have the ability to customize the id or another attribute with your templating engine. Also, you should be able to find a way to access each item as it is bound to the DOM through the templating engine. If not, pick another plugin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you have `id="datepicker"` for all your datepicker inputs, but ids are supposed to be unique in a given DOM. use `class="datepicker"` instead.  and also, since you're using jquery anyways, you dont need to use vanilla javascript `onclick` function.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/331/

```
<div class="mytemplate" style="display: none;">
    <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="name[]"/>
</div>
<div class="dates">
    <div>
        <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="name[]"/>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="addmore" value="Add more">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addmore').on('click', function() {
        $(".mytemplate").clone().removeClass("mytemplate").show().appendTo(".dates");
    });
    $(document).on("focus", ".datepicker", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```